# Some .tiff files are not getting viewed from pdf.js

Tags: java, javascript, pdf.js

I am working on 1 application in which user can upload files and application shows preview of uploaded file using pdf.js. Server side code is:

```
byte[] content= new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(documentVO.getDocument());
                  outPutStream.write(content, 0, content.length);
                  responseReturn.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Problem is for some of the .tiff files preview is not shown and following warning gets displayed on console.
**Warning: Unhandled rejection: [Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://tmc.pw.com:8080/dpg2/Viewer.js/pdf.js :: CanvasGraphics_paintJpegXObject :: line 6511"  data: no]
CanvasGraphics_paintJpegXObject@http://tmc.pw.com:8080/dpg2/Viewer.js/pdf.js:6511:0
CanvasGraphics_executeOperatorList@http://tmc.pw.com:8080/dpg2/Viewer.js/pdf.js:5467:10
InternalRenderTask__next@http://tmc.pw.com:8080/dpg2/Viewer.js/pdf.js:4846:29
InternalRenderTask__continue@http://tmc.pw.com:8080/dpg2/Viewer.js/pdf.js:4838:8
InternalRenderTask_operatorListChanged@http://tmc.pw.com:8080/dpg2/Viewer.js/pdf.js:4827:6
pageDisplayReadyPromise@http://tmc.pw.com:8080/dpg2/Viewer.js/pdf.js:4154:10
runHandlers@http://tmc.pw.com:8080/dpg2/Viewer.js/pdf.js:810:26**

Only some of the .tiff files are getting this warning and preview is not shown.

**NOTE**: If I convert these .tiff files to pdf from any online tiff to pdf converter then it is getting converted without any error, so no issue with the files I guess.

Comment: open bug exists in pdf.js: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2802

Comment: Do you mean your tiff-to-pdf converter produces invalid PDF, however other online converters produce good PDFs? Did you contact viewer.js support?

Comment: @async5 I really don't know whether issue is with viewer.js or while converting tiff to pdf. But getting no exception from backend, on UI it is showing above error

Comment: I think issue is while converting .tiff to pdf,but getting no exception

Answer (score 0):

PDF.js can not render a tiff. It needs a PDF as input file.
In case you have a "real pdf" which produces the problem, please report it at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/new and make sure to provide the pdf which is not working.